# Propensity score matching in spss with R

Tags: r, spss

I'm trying to use the propensity score matching add-on suggested by thommens using spss 22 , r 2.15.3 (also tried 2.15.0) and the spe file of 3.03

When I load the spe file in spss I keep getting errors that there are missing packages (RItools and lme4).
When I try to install them in r, it says there are no versions for 2.15.3 or 2.15.0 so I'm kind of stuck.
I've tried reinstalling and different versions with no success.

Any way to fix that somehow?

Answer (score 1):

When installing packages for obsolete versions of R (and version 2.15.3 is really very obsolete) one must generally use the source versions of the packages. and these often require compilation with the correct set of system tools, which for Windoze means Rtools.exe. both the R packages and the system tools must be from the same time frame. But perhaps the maintainers of the SPSS-R fusion are also maintaining a repository?

Searching for an archival binary Windows repository (which by all rights should have been maintained by IBM for all the versions of R that they have linked to versions of SPSS) I did find such an archive: This should obviate the need for compiling a version of `lme4`. You should change your `options`-setting of "CRAN" to to point to this repository: https://cran-archive.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.15/

The help page: `?options` suggests you do something like:

```
local({r <- getOption("repos")
       r["CRAN"] <- "https://cran-archive.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.15/"
       options(repos = r)})
```

Those zip files that you will see there should not need Rtools to be installed. Also see this Rstudio-hosted article:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages

Searching Google informed me that the advice is specific to only a particular version of SPSS and its derivative "Modeler" facilities. Other versions would require 2.14.x or 3.2.x archives to be specified.